# Storing HashMap inside HashMap

Tags: java

I have tried to store `HashMap` inside another `HashMap` but first inserted values changed as second time inserted value.

Here is my code.

```
   HashMap<String ,HashMap<Integer ,Integer>> map1=new HashMap<>();
   HashMap<Integer ,Integer> map2=new HashMap<>(); 
   map2.put(1,1);
   map2.put(2,1);
   map2.put(3,1); 
   map1.put("1", map2); 
   System.out.println("After Inserting first value   "+map1.entrySet());
   /* OutPut:  After Inserting first value  [1={1=1, 2=1, 3=1}]*/

   map2.clear(); //i cleared map 2 values

   map2.put(4,2); 
   map2.put(5,2); 
   map2.put(6,2); 
   map1.put("2", map2); 
   System.out.println("After Inserting second value   "+map1.entrySet()); 
   /*output :  After Inserting second value    [2={4=2, 5=2, 6=2}, 1={4=2, 5=2, 6=2}]*/
```

The first time I got output as `1={1=1, 2=1, 3=1}]`
after inserting second "key, value" `[2={4=2, 5=2, 6=2}, 1={4=2, 5=2, 6=2}]` I got key "1" values changed to key "2".

Comment: clear affect the object that you stored. put does not make a copy, it keep a direct reference to that object. You need to create a new instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of `HashMap` before the second `put()` call

```
// map2.clear();
map2 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

`Map#clear()` does **not** give you a *new* `Map` instance. Hence, both `map1` keys `1` and `2` end up reusing the *same* instance of `map2` and hence you see all the values repeat themselves.

Try printing your `Map` container after `Map#clear()` and again after adding new values

```
map2.clear(); //i cleared map 2 values
System.out.println("After clearing   "+map1.entrySet()); 

map2.put(4,2); 
map2.put(5,2); 
map2.put(6,2); 
System.out.println("After adding new values   "+map1.entrySet());
```

You can clearly see it affecting key `1` as well.

***Output** :*

```
After Inserting first value   [1={1=1, 2=1, 3=1}]
After clearing   [1={}]
After adding new values   [1={4=2, 5=2, 6=2}]
After Inserting second value   [2={4=2, 5=2, 6=2}, 1={4=2, 5=2, 6=2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You store a reference to the `HashMap` `map2` in `map1`, not a copy. That is why all subsequent changes to `map2` also affect the first map inserted into `map1`.

Answer (score 0):

You SHOULD NOT clear the map. Note that you adding HashMap `map2` which is created with this :

```
HashMap<Integer ,Integer> map2=new HashMap<>();
```

It means there is object created with **adress memory** value. And this address memory value is put into the "bigger" HashMap.

If you clear/change `map2`, you also clear it in your bigger HashMap, because it is just pointing to the **same** object!

You have to create new instance, so instead of

```
map2.clear();
```

You have to do this:

```
map2=new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first inserted values are changed because first reference is referring to map2 and so does second reference. map2 object is same and it is referred in both places.

I guess what you want is create new object for each map2

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing both map. It works.

```
map1.clear();
map2.clear();
```