# Android assign value to two dimension string array

Tags: android, arrays

I want to store city names by country in an array. 
This is my code

```
String cities[][]=new String[10][20];
```

I want to assign all cities of a country one time like this.

```
cities["USA"]={"NEW YORK","WASHINGTON"}
cities["UK"]={"LONDON","CAMBRIDGE","CARLISLE"}
```

then I want to use like this

```
String mycity=cities["UK"][2];
```

but eclipse shows error for assigning values. how can I use this arrays?

Comment: `cities["USA"]` is **wrong**. `cities[0]` is **correct**. Same for the other **index** (not **name**).

Comment: Also you have declared more elements than you fill: **dimensions don't match**. `new String[10][20];` should be `new String[2][3];` in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this,

```
String cities[][]={ 
    {"NEW YORK","WASHINGTON"},
    {"LONDON","CAMBRIDGE","CARLISLE"}
};
```

And

```
cities[0][0]
```

will return **`NEW YORK`**

May be this helps you.

Comment: so how can I get cities of USA if I dont know USA cities index.

Comment: You have to know index friend, Otherwise this method will not help you.

Comment: You can try [`MultiMap`](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashmap-%E2%80%93-single-key-and) and look on [here](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=multimap+in+java+example) too.

Answer (score 1):

Better you can use a HashMap - List combination like this

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<String,List<String>>> cities = new HashMap<>();
```

Refer following links for more details [Storing HashMap inside HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568107/storing-hashmap-inside-hashmap),
[Storing a HashMap inside another HashMap and improving performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864111/storing-a-hashmap-inside-another-hashmap-and-improving-performance)